# Putting logic that depends on the view state in DRF serializer

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

Is it okay to write serializer and its elements (fields, validators) logic to depend on the view state?

For example, I want to write a serializer field validator that checks if the value is true and then checks if the user is authenticated.

I know how to implement such things, but the question is what is more canonical and follows the best practices

1. Put the logic that depends on the view state if some condition is met to the validator (e.g. on serializer and one field for all cases)
2. Or rather have multiple serializer per each case and use overloading per each condition and choose a serializer by checking the condition somewhere up, for example, the view and let the view choose a serializer (e.g. X serializers, one base serializer, X validators)